# Error al usar método con sobrecargas

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo uso de la sobrecarga de métodos siguiendo los distintos tutoriales que encuentro por internet implemente mi clase Empleado_Obrero donde defino las variables con sus respectivos métodos get y set, el problema ocurre al momento de hacer uso de esas sobrecargas de método al tratar de realizar el guardado en una base de datos, adjunto el codigo para saber que estoy realizando de manera no correcta.

```
 class Clase_Empleado_Obrero
    {
        private int _EMPL_COD;
        private string _EMPL_NOMB;
        private string _EMPL_APELL;
        private string _EMPL_DIRE;
        private string _EMPL_CEDU;
        private string _EMPL_TELE;
        private string _EMPL_NOTA;
        private string _EMPL_NOTA_2;
        private int _EMPL_AREA;
        private int _EMPL_RUTA;
        private string _EMPL_ACU_DEC;
        private string _EMPL_CTA_CTE;
        private string _EMPL_CTA_PIC;
        private DateTime _EMPL_FEC_NAC;
        private DateTime _EMPL_FECH;
        private int _EMPL_FECH_AF;
        private int _EMPL_FECH_UAF;
        private DateTime _EMPL_FECH_SA;
        private string _EMPL_STATUS;
        private string _EMPL_MOTIVO;
        private string _EMPL_SEXO;       

        public Clase_Empleado_Obrero()
        {
        }
                    

        public Clase_Empleado_Obrero(int EMPL_COD, string EMPL_NOMB, string EMPL_APELL, string EMPL_DIRE, string EMPL_CEDU, 
            string EMPL_TELE, string EMPL_NOTA, string EMPL_NOTA_2, int EMPL_AREA, int EMPL_RUTA, DateTime EMPL_FEC_NAC, 
            DateTime EMPL_FECH, int EMPL_FECH_AF, int EMPL_FECH_UAF, DateTime EMPL_FECH_SA, string EMPL_STATUS,string EMPL_SEXO)
        {
            this._EMPL_COD = EMPL_COD;
            this._EMPL_NOMB = EMPL_NOMB;
            this._EMPL_APELL = EMPL_APELL;
            this._EMPL_DIRE = EMPL_DIRE;
            this._EMPL_CEDU = EMPL_CEDU;
            this._EMPL_TELE = EMPL_TELE;
            this._EMPL_NOTA = EMPL_NOTA;
            this._EMPL_NOTA_2 = EMPL_NOTA_2;
            this._EMPL_AREA = EMPL_AREA;
            this._EMPL_RUTA = EMPL_RUTA;            
            this._EMPL_FEC_NAC = EMPL_FEC_NAC;
            this._EMPL_FECH = EMPL_FECH;
            this._EMPL_FECH_AF = EMPL_FECH_AF;
            this._EMPL_FECH_UAF = EMPL_FECH_UAF;
            this._EMPL_FECH_SA = EMPL_FECH_SA;
            this._EMPL_STATUS = EMPL_STATUS;            
            this._EMPL_SEXO = EMPL_SEXO;
        }

        public int EMPL_COD { get => EMPL_COD; set => EMPL_COD = value; }
        public String EMPL_NOMB { get => EMPL_NOMB; set => EMPL_NOMB = value; }
        public String EMPL_APELL { get => EMPL_APELL; set => EMPL_APELL = value; }
        public String EMPL_DIRE { get => EMPL_DIRE; set => EMPL_DIRE = value; }
        public String EMPL_CEDU { get => EMPL_CEDU; set => EMPL_CEDU = value; }
        public String EMPL_TELE { get => EMPL_TELE; set => EMPL_TELE = value; }
        public String EMPL_NOTA { get => EMPL_NOTA; set => EMPL_NOTA = value; }
        public String EMPL_NOTA_2 { get => EMPL_NOTA_2; set => EMPL_NOTA_2 = value; }
        public int EMPL_AREA { get => EMPL_AREA; set => EMPL_AREA = value; }
        public String EMPL_RUTA { get => EMPL_RUTA; set => EMPL_RUTA = value; }
        public String EMPL_ACU_DEC { get => EMPL_ACU_DEC; set => EMPL_ACU_DEC = value; }
        public String EMPL_CTA_CTE { get => EMPL_CTA_CTE; set => EMPL_CTA_CTE = value; }
        public String EMPL_CTA_PIC { get => EMPL_CTA_PIC; set => EMPL_CTA_PIC = value; }
        public DateTime EMPL_FEC_NAC { get => EMPL_FEC_NAC; set => EMPL_FEC_NAC = value; }
        public DateTime EMPL_FECH { get => EMPL_FECH; set => EMPL_FECH = value; }
        public int EMPL_FECH_AF { get => EMPL_FECH_AF; set => EMPL_FECH_AF = value; }
        public int EMPL_FECH_UAF { get => EMPL_FECH_UAF; set => EMPL_FECH_UAF = value; }
        public DateTime EMPL_FECH_SA { get => EMPL_FECH_SA; set => EMPL_FECH_SA = value; }
        public String EMPL_STATUS { get => EMPL_STATUS; set => EMPL_STATUS = value; }
        public String EMPL_MOTIVO { get => EMPL_MOTIVO; set => EMPL_MOTIVO = value; }
        public String EMPL_SEXO { get => EMPL_SEXO; set => EMPL_SEXO = value; }
    }
```

Este es el método que realiza el guardado a la base de datos y lo estoy modificando para poder realizar el guardado a través del método de la clase Empleado_Obrero, pero al ejecutar me arroja una excepcion de tipo **StackOverflowException**

```
  public int Ingresar_Empleado_Planta(int codigo, string nombre, string apellido, string direccion, string cedula, string telefono,
             string nota, int area, int ruta, DateTime fechaingreso, int fechaf, string Status, string sexo, DateTime fechaNac)
        {
            SqlCommand command=null;
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO TBL_EMPLEADO (EMPL_COD,EMPL_NOMB,EMPL_APELL,EMPL_DIRE,EMPL_CEDU
                                                    ,EMPL_TELE,EMPL_NOTA,EMPL_AREA,EMPL_RUTA
                                                    ,EMPL_FECH,EMPL_FECH_AF,EMPL_FECH_UAF,EMPL_FECH_SA,EMPL_STATUS,EMPL_SEXO,EMPL_FEC_NAC)
                              VALUES (@EMPL_COD,@EMPL_NOMB,@EMPL_APELL,@EMPL_DIRE,@EMPL_CEDU,@EMPL_TELE,@EMPL_NOTA,@EMPL_AREA,
                                @EMPL_RUTA,@EMPL_FECH,@EMPL_FECH_AF,@EMPL_FECH_UAF,@EMPL_FECH_SA,@EMPL_STATUS,@EMPL_SEXO,@EMPL_FEC_NAC)";

            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    Clases.Clase_Empleado_Obrero IngObr = new Clases.Clase_Empleado_Obrero(codigo, nombre, apellido, direccion, cedula
                        , telefono, nota, nota, area, ruta, fechaNac, fechaingreso, fechaf, fechaf, fechaingreso.AddYears(-1), Status, sexo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_COD", codigo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_NOMB", IngObr.EMPL_NOMB);-- AQUI SE GENERA UNA EXCEPCION
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_APELL", apellido);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_DIRE", direccion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_CEDU", cedula);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_TELE", telefono);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_NOTA", nota);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_AREA", area);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_RUTA", ruta);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FECH", fechaingreso);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FECH_AF", fechaf);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FECH_UAF", fechaf);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FECH_SA", fechaingreso.AddYears(-1));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_STATUS", Status);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_SEXO", sexo);
                    if (fechaNac.ToString() == DateTime.Today.ToString())
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FEC_NAC", fechaNac.AddYears(-18));
                    }
                    else if (fechaNac.ToString() != DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPL_FEC_NAC", fechaNac);
                    }
                    conn.Open();
                    

                }
                
                catch (StackOverflowException _ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + _ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
```

Cabe recalcar que anteriormente funcionaba sin problema pero como es un código que ya fue realizado previamente lo que estoy tratando es dejarlo de la manera mas limpia y optimizada haciendo uso de los constructores y métodos de sobrecarga.

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en tus propiedades. Tomemos la que te da la excepción por ejemplo:

```
public String EMPL_NOMB { 
       get => EMPL_NOMB; 
       set => EMPL_NOMB = value; 
}
```

Cuando se intenta acceder al valor de `EMPL_NOMB`, lo que devuelves es el valor de `EMPL_NOMB`, que a su vez devuelve el valor de `EMPL_NOMB`...y así hasta el infinito. En realidad, hasta que se produce una excepción en la pila de llamadas: el `StackOverFlow`.

La solución es usar las variables privadas que has creado correctamente para almacenar y devolver los valores de la propiedad, algo así:

```
public String EMPL_NOMB { 
       get => this._EMPL_NOMB; 
       set => this._EMPL_NOMB = value; 
}
```

De esta manera, al acceder a `EMPL_NOMB`, devuelves el valor de la variable privada `_EMPL_NOMB`